# change img on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

Using CSS you can change the background with :hover.
Can you do the same with JavaScript?

let's say that you append an img with JavaScript and you want change that image every time a user hover on it can you do it using only CSS? I've tried both (onmouseover with JS and CSS:hover) but every time the "new image" get stuck behind the img created with JavaScript.

### is there a way to replace the "new img" on top of the old one?

here's the code

```
//get api
fetch(api)
  .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    dataFunction(json); 
  });

dataFunction(data){
poster.innerHTML = data.poster
}
```

every time that I mouse over the image i want to change the background with CSS, the new background is set on the back of the API poster though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least two way to solve this problem. First one pure `css` and second one pure `javascript`.
let take a look at first one, you have `data.poster` fetched from your `api` and then insert it as `innerHtml` property of an objet you named poster. i don't know what is your `api` but instead inserting image right into your html, you can some how insert it in `style` tag. let me explaine! I imagine that your `data.poster` might be look like

```
data.poster = '<img src="image_url"/>'
```

if you create that api, then you can change it in this way:

```
data.poster = '<div class="image_on_hover">...</div><style> .image_on_hover{background-image: url("first_url");} .image_on_hover:hover{background-image: url("second_url");} </style>'
```

then insert it like your coded above. Noticed that I just use `css` property to changing background that just need changing a bit in your api. this way is not so good because of
you let your code to insert a certain tag that potentially harmful (maybe some one change your tag in an malicious `script`).
if image that you get from your `api` is not changing each time page loaded, you can hard coded in your `style` instead using `api`, exactly like i do in example before, but hard coded in a `style.css` file.
the second way you could do the same is just using javascript to do so.
for this approach its best that your `api` just send you the url of these images.

```
data.poster = {image1: url_of_image_one, image2: url_of_image_two}
```

then your code must be like this

```
//get api
fetch(api)
  .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    dataFunction(json); 
  });

dataFunction(data){
poster.classNames.add('image_on_hover')
poster.innerHTML += 'data.poster = '<div class="image_on_hover">...</div><style> .image_on_hover{background-image: url("first_url");} .image_on_hover:hover{background-image: url("second_url");} </style>'
}
```

also there is many other ways to solve this, but the general idea is using same property to change the image, for example if you already using some sort of `js` frameworks, like `Vue` you can change it in the `src` of `<img>` tag,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data:{
    image_url: '',
    first_url: '',
    second_url: '',
  },
  methods:{
    hoverOut(){
      if (this.first_url!=='')
        this.image_url = this.first_url;
    },
    hoverIn(){
      if (this.second_url!=='')
        this.image_url = this.second_url;
    },
    fetchData(){
      let that = this;
      fetch(api).then(res=>{
        that.first_url = res.poster.image1;
        that.second_url = res.poster.image2;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
<img :src="image_url" @mouseHover="hoverIn" @mouseout="hoverOut"/>
</div>
```

you can also see this `event` solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492148/animating-a-vue-component-using-mouseover-and-mouseout)

Answer (score 2):

you can have two image tag `onhover` you can change the visibility of the images.

```
.container:hover .second-img {
  visibility: visible;  /*showing second image on hover */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 257px;
}

.second-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
}

.container:hover .second-img {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="first-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff&text=hover+me" />
  <img class="second-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff&text=hello" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a background image for example, you can change it with css, like

```
.myImageClass:hover {
   background-image: new_image.jpg;
}
```

Or you may add a pseudo-element, like:

```
.myClass::after {
   background-image: old_image.jpg;
}
.myClass:hover::after {
   background-image: new_image.jpg;
}
```

It depends on your structure, I can't tell exactly.

As for Javascript, I cant't understand your code... You get a JSON object as a server response, so maybe the data.poster value is not a proper html code. Or, as for me, it's better just to get a plane text with image source address and then insert it in your img.src property:

```
poster.src = data.imageSrc;
```

And also verify and/or change your z-index, this could be a reason of displaying your new image on the back of the previous one.